# How to edit the read data with StreamReader, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, streamreader

I have read a CSV file using a StreamReader. Reading the file is easy, I have 4 columns, each of them are a string, but one (only this is important) has the form "33 kg" and the first row is a headline. I want to remove the first row and the "kg" (its int) of all cells in column B. In WindowsForms I can do this but I am not sure how to do this in WPF.

```
private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // ... Get data.
        var patients = new List<Patient>();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("FHDEGG.txt"))
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (line == null)
                {
                    break;
                }
                patients.Add(new Patient(line));
            }
        }

        // ... Set field.
        this._list = patients;

        // ... Use ItemsSource.
        var grid = sender as DataGrid;
        grid.ItemsSource = patients;
}
```

Comment: Please include the top few rows of the csv file FHDEGG.txt

Comment: Please do not erase your question after you get an answer. Questions and answers are here for others to find, and if the answer helped you, it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between WinForms and WPF is binding mechanism which is allowing us to separate ui logic from domain and business logic. Read about MVVM pattern.

Regarding braking MVVM pattern, in your case you need to crate your own data template for DataGrid columns (in xaml) and then create converter which will convert your value "12 kg" => "12"

**edit
I have forgot about first row- you cannot pass it in to the ItemsSource:), How i wrote create your own column templates and specify headers.
Look here https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/custom-columns/